# How to compare two time instants in an accurate way?

Tags: go, time

I have two time instances. `have` which I fetch from a database and `Now()` time. Once I want to compare them using `After`, the result is not the one which I expected. The instances are as follow:

```
// have => 2022-01-09 09:09:59 +0000 +0000
// now  => 2022-01-09 11:57:08.990265878 +0300 +0300 m=+4.977355713
 
if now.After(have) {
    // ...
}
```

I expected the `true` result from the above condition, while it returns `false`. To figure it out better, I converted them to Unix time with `Unix()` and surprisingly the value of `have` was slightly greater than `now` and that is why the condition returns `false`.

Obviously `now` is after `have` but its Unix time is less than `have`.
As I am wondering regarding the case, would you please let me know where am I wrong?

**Update**
The problem was about time zones.
I have not noticed about it. So I added the following code:

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Local")
    have = have.In(loc)
```

and then once I printed it out, it was like this:

```
have => 2022-01-09 12:09:59 +0300 +0300
```

That is why the condition was returning false.

Comment: 11:57 +0300 is 08:57 UTC. So it's not after 09:09 UTC, it's before.

Comment: @rustyx, exactly, I have not noticed the time zone, and I didn't know that they are also affecting the Unix time.

Comment: Yes, independently of go, unix time is defined to be the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00, Jan 1, 1970 UTC.  So to convert from a local time to unix time, you need to (eg) convert your time to UTC and then subtract it from the above date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two times are in different timezones: `have` is in UTC, and `now` is in `+0300`. Thus you have to subtract 3 hours from the date/time part of the `now` value before comparing it to the other time.